# Install pandas to python3.5 instead of 2.7

Tags: 16.04, python

I'm trying to install pandas. When I do, it's automatically installing to the python installation for v 2.7.

How do I force pandas to install to the python 3.5 installation?

Comment: What commands have you tried?

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-pandas; sudo -H pip install pandas... all of these commands install to 2.7 instead of 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't realize that I needed to run pip3 instead of pip. These steps resolved my issue:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo -H pip3 install pandas
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-pandas` is possible as well.

Comment: @Timo The `pandas` in the Ubuntu repos is probably outdated. Nonetheless, I still wouldn't recommend `sudo -H pip3 install` to install PyPI packages. Instead, a better way to do this is to use a virtual environment.

Answer (score 4):

For Python 3.4.2 Shell, the advice from Timo made the difference:

In the Terminal type

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pandas
```

Then in the python shell type

```
import pandas
```

and no errors!