# How can I use pip to install python packages for python3?

Tags: apt, package-management, python

I don't have enough space on my computer to install Anaconda. First I install python3 using this:

```
sudo apt install spyder3
```

after that, for installing a package, I use this in terminal:

```
pip install pandas
```

after installation, when I want to import pandas, I receive this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Also, when I insert `pip --version` in terminal, I receive this:

```
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

for `pip3 --version`, I receive this:

```
pip 9.0.3 from /home/****/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install pandas to python3.5 instead of 2.7](https://askubuntu.com/q/855901/507051).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using python 3 you need to use `pip3`:

```
pip3 install pandas
```

You've installed `pandas` for python 2.7 not 3 so it won’t work.